# create object in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop, object

What is the difference between that

```
    install=function(s,p){var n;for(n in p)if(p.hasOwnProperty(n))s[n]=p[n]}}
    install(myObj,{userid:"5",username:"john"});
```

To

```
    myObj={userid:"5",username:"john"};
```

?

Comment: you shouldn't think about that too much, you should just code in javascript(the way you want), and in some moment you will see, that the first one can become useful.

Comment: @Dupadupa Why should he not think about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first is using a function, where it (probably) will copy the properties to `myObj`. You will mostly use this when you need to add properties to an already existing object.

The second just creates a new object with the given properties.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to clean-up the code a bit white-space-wise to make it easier to read.

Well, in the first case, you never really create the object myObj. So I guess **that code doesn't even run**.

The second code is how you usually construct anonymous objects.